# Linux: schedule a service to run in a time period

Tags: linux, services, cron

i want a service to be start at 8:00 and be ended in 14:00 automatically

i already do this manualy by:

```
/etc/init.d/myservice.sh start


/etc/init.d/myservice.sh stop
```

i think it should be related to cron jobs. any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
minutes | hour | day | month | day of week | username | command
0         8      *     *       *             myuser    /etc/init.d/myservice.sh start
0         14     *     *       *             myuser    /etc/init.d/myservice.sh stop
```

Replace `myuser` with whatever is appropriate. (probably root)

Also, belongs on serverfault or superuser